# Read file into string each line do

Tags: ruby

I want to read into string and then go through each line of string. I have the following:

```
file = File.read('test.txt')
  file.each_line { |line|
    if line.include?(test)
      puts line
    end
```

I get the error:

```
`include?': no implicit conversion of Array into String (TypeError)
```

Comment: What is `test` and what's the content of `test.txt`?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 5):

```
File.readlines('test.txt').each do |line|
  puts line
end
```

Or this in your case:

```
File.readlines('test.txt').each do |line|
  if line.include? test
    puts line
  end
end
```

p.s.
You said you get error `include?': no implicit conversion of Array into String (TypeError)

It's probably because your `test` variable is an array and not a string
to reproduce your error:

```
test = [1,2,3] #a mistake, It should be string, like '12'
File.readlines('test.txt').each do |line|
  if line.include? test
    puts line
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever is in `test` needs to be a single string. It seems right now that is contains an array. Depending on what you want to do with this, you can rewrite your code in one of two ways.

You can check if any of the strings in your `test` array is in the `line`.

```
if test.any? {|str| line.include?(str) }
  # ...
end
```

or, if you want to ensure that all of the strings in `test` must be contained in the line use this

```
if test.all? {|str| line.include?(str) }
  # ...
end
```